# Can the Chinese visa office issue two visas that are valid at the same time?

Tags: visas, paperwork, china, business-travel

I already have a valid 10-year L-type Chinese visa obtained in 2018 when I traveled to China last year. Now I am planning a tourism trip for 2 weeks followed by a stay in a university where I would lecture UNPAID for 3 weeks (total of 38 hours).

The main purpose of the trip is tourism but, from my readings, I think that I need an F-type visa for those 3 weeks.

So the question is, can the Chinese visa office issue two visas that are valid at the same time? (A new F-type and my present L-type)  If not, are there any options that are roughly equivalent, such as suspending and reinstating the L visa?